# How do you use the phrase "as ... as can be"?

Tags: adjectives, comparisons

I know you can say "happy as can be," but can you use any adjective before "as can be"?

Can I say "I was as American as can be"? or "He was as excited as can be"?

Comment: Yes, you most certainly can. It works with almost anything.

Comment: @WS2 - I'm sure someone will come up with some examples where it doesn't work, but you are correct that it can be fairly broadly applied.

Comment: At this point, I think I'm as nonexistent as I can be.

Answer (score 1):

Many adjectives can precede "as can be". Some are used far more frequently than others, including "happy".

Here's a list of the **top 20 adjectives** that typically come before the expression:

| RANK | CONTEXT | FREQ. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HAPPY | 27 |
| 2 | GOOD | 11 |
| 3 | CUTE | 9 |
| 4 | PLAIN | 6 |
| 5 | SIMPLE | 6 |
| 6 | CASUAL | 4 |
| 7 | CALM | 4 |
| 8 | CLEAR | 4 |
| 9 | COOL | 4 |
| 10 | FRIENDLY | 4 |
| 11 | HOT | 4 |
| 12 | PEACEFUL | 4 |
| 13 | HEALTHY | 3 |
| 14 | MODERN | 3 |
| 15 | FRESH | 3 |
| 16 | DIFFERENT | 3 |
| 17 | PRETTY | 3 |
| 18 | PROUD | 3 |
| 19 | REAL | 3 |
| 20 | SHARP | 3 |

(Courtesy of CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the construction with classifying, absolute and extreme adjectives if you're being tongue-in-cheek or whimsical.

> */?'The bridge is as wooden as can be.'
>
> */?'The weapon is as nuclear as can be.'
>
> */?'The event is as annual as can be.'
>
> */?'He was as dead as could be.'
>
> */?'It is as microscopic as can be.'

But often non-gradable adjectives are treated as gradable with secondary senses:

> as American / alive / full as can be.

Comment: I've certainly heard *As dead as can be*!

Answer (score 0):

Omission of the earlier occurrence of 'as ' in the structure as +adjective +as  will lose nothing but give a colour to the language .Let me proceed with the discussion with an example , 'hey guys , your dance is dull as can be , move on further to give it some welly.'

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Could you provide some research which backs up your answer? It would improve it a lot!