# Is "dead" possible before any adjective?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, compound-adjectives

I've seen combinations like "dead serious", "dead gorgeous" and...

Is it possible to have "dead" before any other adjective(s)? Such as dead difficult or dead stupid? If not, how can one know which combinations are allowed?

Comment: _Absolute, complete, entire, thorough, downright. Also dead-earnest in adj. use._ [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47615?rskey=LkkPAw&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid). I had always assumed that it was a shortening of 'deadly' - in deadly earnest etc. In   colloquial use when I grew up (in Glasgow in the 1960s) we used 'dead' in every context. 'He's dead stupid. She's dead pretty. You're dead rich.'

Comment: I'm dead sure there are others.

Comment: "She was *dead lively* doesn't sound so great." Worse may be *dead alive*. But a teenager might say either. In short, it is the acceptability of (native) speakers that determines  whether such combinations are allowed. @JJJ has suggested that *dead* doesn't work well before "quantifying adjectives," although *dead minimum* sounds fine to me. It really is in the ear of the hearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use the phrase "as ... as can be"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/how-do-you-use-the-phrase-as-as-can-be). You can rarely use intensification with classifying, absolute and extreme adjectives (unless you're being tongue-in-cheek or whimsical). *very nuclear / *very on / *very topmost. 'Dead' also has the complication that it's usually in an informal register.

Comment: There are also other discussions about adjectives (such as 'unique') having both absolute and gradable polysemes (senses). Perhaps the most detailed is at [Are the rules regarding 'absolute-modifiers' too absolute?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44566/are-the-rules-regarding-absolute-modifiers-too-absolute).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's hard to find a rule on which combinations are grammatical or idiomatic and which aren't. One example which to me seems awkward, albeit a bit of a silly example, is *dead* itself. The reason it's awkward, I think, is that **dead** itself is quite final (when talking about humans or animals), i.e. you cannot be a little bit dead, so saying something is *completely* or *very* dead doesn't make much sense.

Of course it could be used when the second dead means something else*. For example a body part that feels awkward due to sitting with crossed legs for a long time.

When your doctor tells you your leg is dead*, you might ask them if it will be over in an hour. If they're into dark humour, they might say it's dead-dead, that is, you're leg starved off (and it may need to be amputated).

*dead meaning:

> If a part of your body is dead, you cannot feel it

#### Dead as an adverb

Yes, dead can be used before an adjective, it then says something about the adjective so the word dead is called an adverb. Note [Cambridge Dictionary's entry for dead](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dead) (2 meanings as an adverb):

> complete(ly), very

Example sentences (from the same source):

> I'm dead hungry.
>
> "How was the film?" "It was dead good."
>
> The exam was dead easy.

Attribution: Definition of “dead” from the Cambridge Business English Dictionary © Cambridge University Press

Comment: Can we use "dead" with any adjective? Are there exceptions?

Comment: @Mari-LouA fair question. For now, consider this a partial answer (mainly addressing the question in the title). Finding exceptions may be easy (although, how do you prove that a certain combination is *not allowed*?). Well, I can think of one, I'll add that

Comment: @Mari-LouA probably dead:  dead dead!

Comment: @lbf yes, although the second dead also adds meaning, consider this [comment on SO by *Željko Filipin* (emphasis is mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854329/watir-wont-choose-the-files-i-need-to-upload#comment8153480_6854329): *Chromewatir is **dead-dead**, I do not think you can even install it any more.*

Comment: I think you can safely delete the first few paragraphs of this answer; the OP is obviously already aware that "dead" can be used before *certain* adjectives. (I think you misinterpreted the word "any" in the question title; you read it in the negative-polarity sense, but the OP intended it in a positive sense. Cf. "'Dead' is possible before *any* adjective.")

Comment: @ruakh fair point, I hadn't considered that. I've put the reasoning behind using dead as an adverb at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: ["Dead dead" is actually not that uncommon](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=XGL8WquqA8fejwSWxK2ABQ&q=%22dead+dead+or+just%22&oq=%22dead+dead+or+just%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21818.22477.0.22657.5.5.0.0.0.0.82.318.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.AmnMYKC9nfU) to emphasize *actually* dead (vs figuratively dead or dead-but-revivable etc.), but this is probably more a case of reduplicative emphasis than the OP's usage—cf. "do you like him, or do you *like him* like him?" I think "dead alive" sounds pretty weird, though.

Comment: @1006a good example, I've actually thought of some more examples which don't sound very well: *dead big*, *dead very*, *dead minor*, *dead minimum*, *dead thousandth*. It seems *dead* doesn't work well with quantifying adjectives.

Comment: @lbf 'Dead dead' is probably acceptable if understood as a reduplication (as in 'It's coffee, perhaps, but it's not _coffee_ coffee.') 'Moriarty is dead, but is he _dead_ dead?'