# as ... as can be

Tags: idioms

I have read this post: [How do you use the phrase "as ... as can be"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285653/how-do-you-use-the-phrase-as-as-can-be)

What I have in question is whether I can use the phrase in the following ways:

> I told him in **as** euphemistic a way **as can be**.

or

> I told him in a way **as** euphemistic **as can be**.

Comment: The expression usually sounds at least faintly childrens-story-register, and trying to use it in any way with 'euphemistically' etc sounds ludicrous. I'm not sure that 'euphemistically' grades well in any way. I'd rephrase.

Comment: ...and then there's the verb tense issue *(I **told** him as euphemistically as **could** be)*. Maybe better to switch to *I told him **as diplomatically / delicately as possible**.*

Comment: So - were Cinderella's sisters as ugly as can be? Or as ugly as ***could*** be? They both sound fine to me.

Comment: It's a fixed phrase with only an adjective variable when you say _as can be_. Anything else requires a less abbreviated phrase or clause than _can be_. You can say _He was as handsome as can/could be_, but not *_He was as furious at her as could be;_ it would have to be something like _as furious with her as he could be/have been_ and of course that loses the effect.

Comment: The first one functions like a prepositional phrase, and the second, adjective phrase. Both are right to me.